# pushing a commit changes the commit message for the entire path in repository

Tags: git, github

Practicing github as of late and decided to push some of my code to a repository.
I then changed a part of a program and when I pushed the change with git- the commit message I used for the program (after `git add abc.py`) was pushed to all of the previous folders in the path containing the file, i.e., in my repository named `practice`, the path of the file is

`foo/baz/abc.py`

where foo and baz both show the same commit message I used for abc.py.

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong here.

What can I do to ensure that my commit messages stay limited to the file I am making changes to (abc.py here)?

Comment: You're starting with some sort of very wrong idea. I'm not entirely sure what it is, but let's note two things here: (1) A Git repository consists mainly of commits and each commit is a *full snapshot of every file* so your new commit with changes in `abc.py` also holds *every other file too*, as a full snapshot. Git will show a commit as "changes since previous commit" but to do that, Git extracts *both commits* and *compares the files*.

Comment: (2) A commit never stores any folders. It stores only *files*. The files in a Git commit may have path names that contain forward slashes (`foo/baz/abc.py`). Git understands that your OS demands that such a file, once *extracted from* a commit, must be stored as an OS-level file named `abc.py` in a folder named `baz` in a folder named `foo`. But for the purpose of the commit, there are no folders here, just a file with the name `foo/baz/abc.py`, all as one big long string.

Comment: This really helped and thank you for clearing up my fundamental misconceptions. I had an idea about the second point but I was not sure. 


But from what I have seen of other open source repositories, say, gRPC, now, for a lack of better vocabulary, has a path name called `doc` which has the message `orca oob test verification timeout` associated with itself and contains some files inside of it which all have nearly different messages attached to it. 
How exactly can I achieve the same with git bash? @torek

Comment: I have a thought about this. Does github reflect the latest commit on the entire "string" no matter how many path names you have?


If that is true, then it seems like I was searching for a solution that never existed all this time

Comment: Yes, GitHub have a weird way to present the actual information from the repository: for each file, they look for the commit that most recently *modified* that file, and display some information extracted from it. This is sometimes actually useful  but highly misleading ... especially when applied to a directory.

Comment: I feel conflicted, frustrated, relieved, upset and glad at the same time. Something which would have merely taken a couple of minutes to notice if I opened any public repo took me three days just because I didn't.